# Laravel sub-domain routing without passing variable to URL::route()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In a Laravel 4 app, i'm using subdomain routing around a bunch of Route::resource's like this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.my.app'], function()
{
    Route::group(['before' => 'auth'], function($account)
    {
        Route::resource('organisations', 'OrganisationsController');
        Route::resource('clients', 'ClientsController');
        Route::resource('domains', 'DomainsController');
    });
});
```

In my auth filter i'm doing the following:

```
Route::filter('auth', function($route)
{
    // you could now access $account in a controller if it was passed as an argument to the method
    $account = $route->getParameter('account');

    // share account variable with all views
    View::share('account', $account);

    // Auth::guest Returns true if the current user is not logged in (a guest).
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Within my views I can now access `$account`, but if I want a call to `URL::route()` to be correct I have to manually pass the account variable, like `URL::route('clients.show',['account' => $account])` otherwise it generates URLs like `%7Baccount%7D.my.app`.

This is a bit of a pain and doesn't seem that elegant, is there any other or better way to achieve this? I guess I could create my own route helper to use instead of the built-in one.
However, I also do redirects with Redirect::route() within controllers so I would also need to make updates here.

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments it may be that extending the Route API is the best approach here. Does anyone have any suggestions how this should be done?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to extend the Route API: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html

Comment: Nope, that's how they work mate. I'm fairly sure you don't need to do `['account' => $account]`, you should be able to just pass them in in the order they are defined, so `[$account]` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks guys. One problem with declaring the variable inline is that i'll also have to do this every time I call Redirect::route() also. Extending the route API does seem preferable in that regard although i'm not sure if this is going to just create more problems.

Comment: I'd create my own helper (similar to Laravel `route()` method, and in each of your `Redirect::route()`, I'd change them to `Redirect::to(customroute())`. Then start using them moving forward.

Comment: Would you write an example how you solve it? @seengee